# spark rdd how to flat Key - Array(value) pair

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, flatmap

I have a park paired rdd (key, Array(value1, value2, value3.....)).
what scala statement should I wrote?
How could I flat this rdd and creating a new rdd : (key, value1), (key, value2), (key, value3)....

Comment: probably just `rdd.flatMapValues(x=>x)`

Answer (score 1):

As @moto said, it is simply

`rdd.flatMapValues(v => v)`

A more verbose but arguably more readable option:

```
rdd.flatMap {
   case (key, values) => values.map(v => key -> v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rdd.flatMap{case (k,v) => v.map(vx => (k,vx))}
```